# Are Okta group names unique?

Tags: okta

Reference - https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/groups/#group-attributes

In a group object, an `id` is unique, though the [`profile`](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/groups/#objectclass-okta-user-group) is not unique. The `profile` contains the `name` and `description` of a group.

Does this mean that Okta doesn't ensure that groups have unique names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Okta enforces this at least on the UI when trying to create a group with same name.

Note: this might not be true for groups created with sync (and thus the documentation puts it like that). Couldn't run that experiment for lack of resources.

[image: Okta error screen]

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can have more than one group with the same name